# How to create a custom class that inherits from Task<T> to use in an async method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm currently updating my solution to match Microsoft All Rules using Visual Studio Code Analysis.

I have an interface which can fetch entities from a database using async, this is done with the following method signature:

```
Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> EntitiesAsync();
```

The implementation of this method looks like:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> EntitiesAsync()
{
    DbSet.ThrowIfNull("DbSet");

    IQueryable<TEntity> returnList = null;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (OnBeforeEntityGetAll != null)
        { OnBeforeEntityGetAll(this, new RepositoryEventArgs(typeof(TEntity))); }

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        if (OnEntityGetAll != null)
        { OnEntityGetAll(this, new RepositoryEventArgs(typeof(TEntity))); }

        returnList = query.AsQueryable();
    });

    return returnList;
}
```

So far so good, this code is working, but the Code Analysis is making some noise saying:

> [CA1006](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182144.aspx): **Do not nest generic types in member signatures.**

This basiclly means that I'm returning nested types, in this case `Task<IQuerable<TEntity>>`

I tought that I should be able to solve this issue by creating a class that extends this one and that might look like:

```
public class AsyncQueryResult<TEntity> : Task<IQueryable<TEntity>>
{
    public AsyncQueryResult(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>> function)
        : base(function)
    { }
}
```

This does mean that I need to update my method signature to be:

```
AsyncQueryResult<TEntity> EntitiesAsync();
```

When I change my implementation method accordingly:

```
public async AsyncQueryResult<TEntity> EntitiesAsync()
{ }
```

I do receive a compiler error telling me:

*The return type of an async must be Void, Task or Task{T}.*

I hope someone does have a clear idea on how I should be able to solve this issue.

Comment: What's the point in following all the Code Analysis rules? This one clearly doesn't make sense here, your code is totally fine.

Comment: I know that my code is fine and working, but I would like to know why I cannot inherit from Task<T>. Let's say that I want to return additional properties and not only the IQueryable<TEntity>, what would be the solution here?

Comment: Use `Task<Tuple<IQueryable<TEntity>, SomethingElse>>` or `Task<Something>` where `Something` contains your queryable and additional properties. You can only return `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>` from method marked with `async` modifier because that's what spec says.

Comment: What's the point of `await Task.Run()`? If you're going to run the code synchronously by waiting on it, you might as well put it in the method body. In fact, there's no asynchronous code in your method at all, so the simplest fix is to change the return type to `IQueryable<TEntity>` and leave out the `Task` stuff altogether.

Comment: I tought that I was missing something with the async stuff. You mind provide me an update on how to make my method implementation being async?

Comment: From version 6 onwards, Entity Framework (as I assume that's what you're using) has `*Async()` implementations of query results (e.g. `ToListAsync()`). In this particular case, it appears you are not actually executing any query (since you're just returning an `IQueryable`, which is deferred), so you can leave that to your caller.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand. My knowledge of async is non-existing. I just have a method which I would like to run async, so how should I do this?

Comment: @Complexity: that's a great question and I wish you'd open a new SO question just for that! The basic idea is: don't write `async` wrappers if your code isn't asynchronous. Let your callers (the ones that really need to continue without waiting) use `Task.Run()` and the like.